# using rsync to sync remote directories in different windows servers

Tags: windows, cwrsync

I have a WebLogic base install this time on windows and I am trying to create a method to patch in one windows server and sync it remotely with several other servers.  I was able to make it work in RedHat but windows is next.  I heard of cwRsync  but seems to be a utility that needs to be purchased.  I would like to see if I can make it work without purchasing software.
FYI the WL base install is identical. same dir same drive same input during the install.
I know I can use oPatch but I would like to sync it instead.
also it is only a base install no domain.
windows version is windows server 2008.

Regards

Comment: Are you looking just to sync folders between Windows computers?

Comment: correct only windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many free Windows utilities for syncing folders between computers,
although this question comes close to being off-subject on our site.

Examples:

- Microsoft's [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)
- [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/)
- [TeraCopy](https://codesector.com/teracopy)

Comment: robocopy seems to be the best candidate. I am hesitant to install programs  but robocopy is existing in windows. thank you.